# EasySNMP: Different output converting OCTETSTR to Hex

Tags: python, hex, snmp, octetstring

When I use the function `encode` to convert OCTET to Hex, some characters are add when it shouldn't.

Example:

Linux: 
`snmpwalk -t 5 -v2c -c public 192.168.10.150 iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1`

SNMPWALK output: `iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.144 = Hex-STRING: AC 84 C6 5F 95 EF B0 4E 26 8B 1C C5 C0 4A 00 AE`

Code:

```
session = Session(hostname='192.168.10.150', community='public', version=2)
description = session.walk('iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1')

for item in description:
    print '{oid}.{oid_index} {snmp_type} = {value}'.format(
         oid=item.oid,
         oid_index=item.oid_index,
         snmp_type=item.snmp_type,
         value=item.value.encode("hex"))
```

EasySNMP output: `iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.144. OCTETSTR = c2acc284c3865fc295c3afc2b04e26c28b1cc385c3804a00c2ae59c293c2b04e26c28b4ec2ad`

Some OIDs are used, but the output is different from what I expected. Is it the correct the way to use easysnmp?

### Packet Capture

SNMPWalk (Linux):

```
    192.168.10.214  192.168.10.150  get-next-request 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1 Value(NULL)
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    data: get-next-request (1)
        get-next-request
            request-id: 686772965
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 1 item
                1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1: Value (Null)
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1)
                    Value (Null)

    192.168.10.150  192.168.10.214  get-response 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.51 
Value(00:02:18:a6:f7:65:88:f5:18:a6:f7:65:18:a6:f7:65:88:f5:b0:4e:26:8a:e3:cb:50:c7:bf:f2:db:95:b0:4e:26:ed:8d:c5:98:de:d0:76:e3:01:00:02:98:de:d0:76)
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    data: get-response (2)
        get-response
            request-id: 686772965
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 1 item
                1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5: 000218a6f76588f518a6f76518a6f76588f5b04e268ae3cb...
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5)
                    Value (OctetString): 000218a6f76588f518a6f76518a6f76588f5b04e268ae3cb...


    192.168.10.214  192.168.10.150  get-next-request 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5 Value(NULL)
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    data: get-next-request (1)
        get-next-request
            request-id: 686772966
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 1 item
                1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5: Value (Null)
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5)
                    Value (Null)


    192.168.10.150  192.168.10.214  get-response 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.2.48 Value(70:4f:57:4d:cc:cf:b0:4e:26:8b:45:11:ac:84:c6:1d:0e:c5:70:4f:57:3a:dd:5b:70:4f:57:4c:92:8f:b0:4e:26:8a:ef:99)
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    data: get-response (2)
        get-response
            request-id: 686772966
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 1 item
                1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.2.48: 704f574dcccfb04e268b4511ac84c61d0ec5704f573add5b...
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.2.48 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.2.48)
                    Value (OctetString): 704f574dcccfb04e268b4511ac84c61d0ec5704f573add5b...
```

EasySNMP:

```
    192.168.10.214  192.168.10.150  get-next-request 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1 Value(NULL)
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    data: get-next-request (1)
        get-next-request
            request-id: 1767019562
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 1 item
                1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1: Value (Null)
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1)
                    Value (Null)


    192.168.10.150  192.168.10.214  get-response 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5 Value(00:02:18:a6:f7:65:88:f5:18:a6:f7:65:18:a6:f7:65:88:f5:b0:4e:26:8a:e3:cb:50:c7:bf:f2:db:95:b0:4e:26:ed:8d:c5:98:de:d0:76:e3:01:00:02:98:de:d0:76)
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    data: get-response (2)
        get-response
            request-id: 1767019562
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 1 item
                1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5: 000218a6f76588f518a6f76518a6f76588f5b04e268ae3cb...
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5)
                    Value (OctetString): 000218a6f76588f518a6f76518a6f76588f5b04e268ae3cb...



    192.168.10.214  192.168.10.150  get-next-request 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5 Value(NULL)
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    data: get-next-request (1)
        get-next-request
            request-id: 1767019563
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 1 item
                1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5: Value (Null)
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1.5)
                    Value (Null)


    192.168.10.150  192.168.10.214  get-response 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.2.48 VALUE(70:4f:57:4d:cc:cf:b0:4e:26:8b:45:11:ac:84:c6:1d:0e:c5:70:4f:57:3a:dd:5b:70:4f:57:4c:92:8f:b0:4e:26:8a:ef:99)
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    data: get-response (2)
        get-response
            request-id: 1767019563
            error-status: noError (0)
            error-index: 0
            variable-bindings: 1 item
                1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.2.48: 704f574dcccfb04e268b4511ac84c61d0ec5704f573add5b...
                    Object Name: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.2.48 (iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.2.48)
                    Value (OctetString): 704f574dcccfb04e268b4511ac84c61d0ec5704f573add5b...
```

Comment: Can you show is a packet capture (in e.g. Wireshark) for this request and response, in both cases?

Comment: Can you point us to or show us the MIB definition for this object?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Do you want to know if the response in both case, using wireshark are returning the same values?

Comment: About MIB definition, Where do I find it? Mib File???

Comment: Yes, that's what we want to know - but more than knowing whether they're the same, knowing what they _are_ will help us to understand the situation. As for the MIB, I cannot know that, only you can know that. It's wherever you put it! Or are you not using one for some reason? Why not?

Comment: Oh right, I'm requesting the MAC Address which are connected to ONU. I'm confused with the packets, Can I send by email?

Comment: You could paste (as text) the contents of the packets as reported by Wireshark (or some other packet capture application) into your question. I still would like to see the MIB that states the rules for how this address information is intended to be interpreted; you can't work out how it's "supposed" to work without that!

Comment: I Pasted the contents, is it right? About MIB, This hardware does not have a  well defined documentation, I got just the mib file.

Comment: I'm looking for some information about that MIB, I found this `uc olt dynmic bridgeemac`

Comment: Almost but we need to see the structural contents of the packet(s). It should be in the bottom pane when you select the relevant packet.

Comment: Do you wanna both get-next-request and get-request, or one of that is enough?

Comment: Presumably you mean get-response. It's the get-response we care about but may as well check the request too

Comment: Ohh, sorry. Yes, I'll provide them

Comment: Well, the pane you said it shows the protocol stack, you want the information reference which protocol, just SNMP?

Comment: It'll look like the image on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25399610/560648), but with the data bit expanded too. We need to see the contents of the messages. It could be deduced from the hex you've provided in your last edit, but that's too much work :P

Comment: Done, I guess it's enough :p

Comment: Yeah might be able to do something with that - will get back to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. We can tell the following:

- The requests are identical from both managers
- The responses to both requests are identical

This means that either the Net-SNMP output is "mangled"/transformed, or the EasySNMP output is.

Unfortunately the packet captures don't show the interactions that were described in the original version of the post, so we cannot immediately tell which manager is at fault. However, it is possible to make a deduction based on the values that we see.

Your Python script's output is almost a superset of the snmpwalk output:

- Net-SNMP:

  - **AC 84** C6 **5F 95** EF **B0 4E 26 8B 1C** C5 C0 **4A 00 AE**
- Python script:

  - C2 **AC** C2 **84** C3 86 **5F** C2 **95** C3 AF C2 **B0** **4E** **26** C2 **8B** **1C** C3 85 C3 80 **4A** **00** C2 **AE** 59 C2 93 C2 B0 4E 26 C2 8B 4E C2 AD

So why have additional bytes been added, and why have some bytes been lost? This smells like a re-encoding of the source data, right?

We can observe that byte C2 pops up a lot. What's that? It's the "extended ASCII" (there's actually no such thing, but in many codepages) for the character Â. Aha, red flag. Why's it a red flag? Because [this is commonly evidence of misinterpreted UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55094229/560648). (I could explain in more detail *why* this is, but I'll let you research Unicode encodings separately if you desire.)

So, using [an online tool](https://mothereff.in/utf-8) or [two](https://cryptii.com/pipes/unicode-lookup), let's decode that second byte stream as UTF-8 and see what logical codepoints we get:

> **U+AC U+84 U+C6 U+5F U+95 U+EF U+B0 U+4E U+26 U+8B U+1C U+C5 U+C0 U+4A** **U+AE** U+59 U+93 U+B0 U+4E U+26 U+8B U+4E U+AD

Hey, that looks familiar! (Again, I've bolded the bits that match the Net-SNMP output.) U+00 is missing (presumably because [that is a "null" byte much as in ASCII](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf)) and there's still a bunch of noise at the end (if you're interested, they render like this: *"Y°N&N­"*), but we can now at least see what's going on: your original byte stream has been re-encoded as a UTF-8 string. Indeed, [Python 3's default encoding is UTF-8](https://learn.rmotr.com/python/understanding-unicode-in-python/strings-and-unicode/encodings-and-utf-8).

The reason that bytes like C6 disappeared entirely is that they fall outside of the ASCII range, so map "uncleanly" in Unicode. ASCII C6, it turns out, [is U+00C6, which is represented in UTF-8 by C3 86](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c6/index.htm), so now we know where the unbolded bytes come from, too.

So, EasySNMP is treating your walk result as a *string* rather than as an opaque sequence of bytes, and as a result Python has mangled it. Then, when you wrote `.encode("hex")`, you got the hex-pair representation of this new, falsified UTF-8 string.

This should probably not be happening. The SNMP response is clearly indicated as an "OctetString", and the spec tells us that [*"The `OCTET STRING` type represents arbitrary binary or textual data"*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#section-7.1.2). The MIB (which you do not appear to be using, or at least have not provided) for the agent with which you are communicating may provide further encoding information; in the absence of that information, there's no way to know for sure how an `OCTET STRING` should be displayed. For example, [this Net-SNMP bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/bugs/2815/) discusses literally making a *guess* when applicable.

Anyway, all very interesting, but what can we do about it?

The EasySNMP docs are fairly thin, but we can poke around in the source code a bit (and, in the process, discover that [EasySNMP is actually just a Python wrapper around Net-SNMP!](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/easysnmp/blob/master/easysnmp/interface.c)) and on the EasySNMP issues list, where it turns out [someone's complained about this before](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/easysnmp/issues/51).

Again, then, what can we do about it?

Um, I'm not sure that there's much we *can* do about it. This is currently a flaw in EasySNMP. Things are Unicodised (either by EasySNMP itself, by way of conversion to Python strings, or by the Net-SNMP compat module described earlier) even when they should not be.

However, [this chap has suggested a workaround](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/easysnmp/issues/96#issuecomment-397292022) that you could try:

```
session = Session(
   hostname='192.168.10.150',
   community='public',
   version=2,
   use_sprint_value=False
)
```

That new final argument ought to turn off value transformation. However, I'm not convinced, because [per the docs](https://easysnmp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/session_api.html) it's already `False` by default.

Beyond trying it anyway, I think your best bet is to add your weight to the relevant issue report(s) and pressure the developer to come up with a fix. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer friend. I understand, what do you suggest? I mean, which solution I can use? Today I'm running a bash script (snmpwalk) inside python, which writes a file and the python manipulate it. but I think that's too slow

Comment: _"I think your best bet is to add your weight to the relevant issue report(s) and pressure the developer to come up with a fix. Sorry."_ You're doing what I would probably do as a workaround. Obviously the library being "fixed" would be much better.

Comment: I was thinking another library, but I'll do it, obviously it will be the best for community. Again, thanks very much for you reply

Comment: @TMoraes Ah ok - I don't know what other libraries are around. Let us know if you find a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're having the same issue that I have. I've talked about it [on Github recently as well](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/easysnmp/issues/51). Compat.py within the library is encoding the data as latin-1 instead of utf-8.

Regardless, based on your original code example the following should work:

```
session = Session(hostname='192.168.10.150', community='public', version=2)
description = session.walk('iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.1.1.1')

for item in description:
    print '{oid}.{oid_index} {snmp_type} = {value}'.format(
         oid=item.oid,
         oid_index=item.oid_index,
         snmp_type=item.snmp_type,
         value=item.value.encode("latin-1").hex())
```

This will give you the hex as a continuous string. If you'd rather it as a bytes object just leave off the '.hex()' in value.

You could also do some comparisons if you wanted to be sure if you know the hex with something like:

```
from easysnmp import snmp_get

OID = iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.7.2520.9.1
foo = snmp_get(OID, hostname='192.0.2.1', community='public', version=2).value.encode('latin-1')
foo == bytes.fromhex("312f3300")
```

In that example we're assuming the OID is returning the 31 2F 33 00 hex value for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

To get the right hex value, I'm using this.

```
     def toRaw(s):
       x = [ord(i) for i in list(s)]
       return bytearray(x)
     
     print(toRaw(item.value).hex().upper())
```