# how to convert utf8 to std::string?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-16, cjk, cpprest-sdk

I am working on this code which receives a cpprest sdk response containing a base64_encoded payload which is a json. here is my code snippet:

```
typedef std::wstring string_t; //defined in basic_types.h in cpprest lib
    void demo() {
        http_response response; 
        //code to handle respose ...
        json::value output= response.extract_json();
        string_t payload = output.at(L"payload").as_string();
        vector<unsigned char> base64_encoded_payload = conversions::from_base64(payload);
        std::string utf8_payload(base64_encoded_payload.begin(), base64_encoded_payload.end()); //in debugger I see the Japanese chars are garbled.
        string_t utf16_payload = utf8_to_utf16(utf8_payload); //in debugger I see the Japanese chars are good here
        //then I need to process the utf8_payload which is an xml.
        //I have an API available to process the xml which takes an string
        processXML(utf16_payload); //need to convert utf16_payload to a string here;

    }
```

I also tried this and I see str contains garbled chars!

```
#include <codecvt>  // for codecvt_utf8_utf16
#include <locale>   // for wstring_convert
#include <string>   // for string, wstring
void wstr2str(void) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conversion;
    std::wstring japanese = L"北島 美奈";
    std::string str = conversion.to_bytes(japanese); //str is garbled:(
}
```

my questions is: can utf8 containing Japanese char be converted to std::string without being garbled?

**Update:** I gained access to the **processXML()** code and changed the input argument type to std::wstring and it worked.
I figured when the xml was getting created, it was converting the std::string to wstring; however, it was not turning out good!

```
void processXML(std::wstring xmlStrBuf) { //chaned xmlStrBuf to wstring and worked
// more code
CComBSTR xmlBuff = xmlStrBuf.c_str(); 
VARIANT_BOOL bSuccess = false;
xmlDoc->loadXML(xmlBuff, &bSuccess);
//more code
```

}

Thanks for the answers and they were helpful when mentioned the string is only a storage.

Comment: `std::string` can store utf8 as it is, so there should be no need to convert.

Comment: If you want UTF-8, why are you trying to convert _to_ UTF-16? What do you mean by "a string", exactly?

Comment: when I converted to utf-16, I could see the Japanese chars are not garbled. that is why I thought I might need to convert it and then convert it to string, so I can pass it to the processXML which takes string.

Comment: Encoding the Japanese characters as UTF-8 rather than `wchar_t` UTF-16 or UTF-32 (depending on your platform).

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing different concepts here.

**Storage**

This is how we save/store/hold our data. A `std::string` is a collection of `char`s, which are *bytes*. A `std::wstring` is a collection of `wchar_t`s, which are sometimes 2-byte wide value (but this is not guaranteed!).

**Encoding**

This is what the data *means*, and how it should be interpreted. A `std::string`, a collection of bytes, could hold UTF-8, or UTF-16, or UTF-32, or ASCII, or ShiftJIS, or morse code, or a JPEG, or a movie, or my DNA (lucky string!).

There are some strong conventions in play in the world. For example, on Windows, a `std::wstring` is generally accepted to hold UTF-16 (because the two-byte storage is convenient for this, and also because that's how the Windows API does it).

Newer versions of C++ give us things like `std::u16_string` and `std::u32_string` as well, which still do not *directly* have any notion of encoding, but are intended to be used for UTF-16 and UTF-32 respectively because their names make that intention more obvious to readers of code. C++20 will introduce `std::u8_string` which is intended to signify a UTF-8 encoded string (and is otherwise more or less like a `std::string`).

But these are just *conventions*. Nothing about the type `std::string` says "UTF-8" or any other thing. It doesn't know about or care about or enforce any encoding. It just stores bytes.

So, your question about "converting UTF-8 to `std::string`" does not really make any sense; it's like asking how to convert a road into a car.

**"What should I do, then?"**

Well, Base64 is also not an encoding. Well, actually, it totally is, but it's an encoding *on top of* the string encoding. It's a way of transmitting/escaping/sanitising the raw bytes, not a way of describing how to interpret them later. By [asking cpprest to convert from Base64](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaceutility_1_1conversions.html#aff2e479f0fb5a278935648fe8a0d4abb), that's just transforming the way the raw bytes are provided. That's why it gives you a `std::vector<char>` rather than a `std::string` because, although (as discussed above) `std::string` doesn't care about encoding, we sometimes use a `std::vector<char>` to really, properly, completely say that "this collection does not have any particular encoding, so please don't try to guess from convention or whatever what the encoding is in this use case; all it knows is that it is a bunch of bytes". This is down to opinion. Some people will still use a `std::string` for that; the authors of cpprest decided not to.

The point is that the use of the function `from_base64` cannot tell us anything about the encoding of the text that you've retrieved. For that, we have to go back to the documentation for the text. We have no access to that, and you did not tell us anything about it. If it were just a JSON string, the encoding would be down to the cpprest JSON library and so you'd already be done. However, it's not: it's something packed into a Base64 representation by whoever created the JSON object. Again, that information is not something that you shared with us.

But, based on the variable names you've chosen, the data you're looking at *is already UTF-8*. You've then attempted to convert it to UTF-16, which is rather the opposite of what you've described you wanted to do.

(Similarly, in your second example, you've taken [a `std::wstring` that [probably] already stores UTF-16 thanks to the `L"wide string literal"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1810343/560648), then told the computer that it's UTF-8 and to convert it "again" to UTF-16, then extracted the raw bytes into a `std::string`. None of that makes sense.)

Instead, why not literally just `processXML(utf8_payload);`?

**General advice**

Encoding can be quite complex, although it's significantly easier to deal with once you've wrapped your mind around the basic concepts of all these layers of abstraction. For the future, and for this question if you wish to clarify it, you will need to ensure that you are absolutely clear, at each stage of the "pipeline" of your data as it gets transmitted from place A to place B, and gets converted from type C to type D, and whatever else, about what encoding it should be at each of those steps. If you want to change the encoding at one of those steps, then do so (though this should be rare!). But before you write any code make sure that you know for sure what it is that you need, otherwise you'll get yourself in a massive tangle.

Eventually you'll start to detect patterns that can help, though. For example, if you were expecting some delicious non-ASCII output and instead see strange text with lots of *"Å"* characters in it, that's probably UTF-8 that's being interpreted as ASCII by mistake. That's because of the way that the special sequence denoting Unicode codepoints larger than one byte in UTF-8 often starts with a byte whose numerical value is the same as that of the letter *"Å"* in ASCII (well, ISO/IEC 8859, but close enough).

Similarly, if you get Japanese and didn't expect it, in my experience that's usually because you've given the computer some bytes and told it that they are a string in UTF-16 encoding, when actually they were UTF-8. You just get more experienced at recognising these patterns as you work more, and it can help you to fix your bugs faster.

Just last week the last example there saved me quite a bit of time: I knew immediately that my source data must have been UTF-8, and was therefore able to quickly decide to remove the byte-copy into a `std::wstring` that I'd been attempting. Examining the bytes in an encoding-agnostic way revealed the *"Å"* pattern as well and then that was that. This was important because I had no documentation for the data source and thus no way to just look up what the encoding was *supposed* to be. I had to guess/deduce it. Hopefully that won't be the case for you here.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is just a container for 8-bit wide `char`, and does not know/care about the encoding. Always think in symbols (letters, numbers, punctuation, etc.) The first 128 characters (0-127) were defined per the ASCII standard, thus requiring a single `char` to store each symbol. With all the languages and symbols there is, we couldn't represent each of them with just 256 possibilities. The UTF-8 encoding introduces a way to deal with this problem by allowing a single symbol to take 1, 2, 3 or 4 `char` wide. But, for the `std::string` object, this is entirely transparent and it's still dealing with a series of chars.

The reason why you're thinking the string is garbled is probably because your debugger assumes the contents of the `std::string` is always 1 symbol per char (extended ASCII for example), and as such, it's displaying the wrong characters.

Edit: you might want to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264818/storing-unicode-utf-8-string-in-stdstring) also.

Comment: I am aware of std::string just could represent 256, but I am limited to to it because the processXML() take std::string as argument. the processXML() is the one that writes the xml to DB and then I get only "??????" for the Japanese chars.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `std::string` for UTF-8, because UTF-8 is a standard encoding that describes how a Unicode string can be described in a sequence of bytes, and each byte (by design, assuming we mean "octets", which we do) may only hold a numerical value up to 255. There is nothing fatally limiting about this. In fact, it's the best choice; you just need to be aware of it when you're manipulating said byte sequence, and when you're re-interpreting it as a sequence of glyphs (which is what your terminal application does)

Comment: Somewhere along the way _you're not doing that_ but we don't have enough information to tell you where or how or why.